# not a valid xpath expression driver.find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, xpath

Can't figure out whats wrong, please help.

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@required autocomplete="cc-number"]')
```

The string `'//input[@required autocomplete="cc-number"]'` is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: It's obvious what's wrong (see answers), but to tell you how to fix it, we need to see what your source XML looks like, and we need to know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`required` and `autocomplete` are two separate attributes so you'd need to combine them with "and":

```xml
//input[@required and @autocomplete="cc-number"]
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@required and @autocomplete="cc-number"]"}

Comment: <input required="" autocomplete="cc-number" id="number" name="number" type="tel" aria-describedby="error-for-number tooltip-for-number" data-current-field="number" class="input-placeholder-color--lvl-22" placeholder="Card number" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;, sans-serif; padding: 0.94em 0.8em; transition: padding 0.2s ease-out 0s;">